# Exibir (res.send()) constante declarada dentro da função

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, axios

Olá, pessoal.

Estou tentando exibir um array de objetos no meu navegador, a partir de dados requisitados em outra API. Porém, ao exportar o caminho para devolver a requisição do navegador, o valor apresentado é apenas um **{ }**.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { application } = require('express');
const url = 'https:/site.com/contacts';
const apiHeaders = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

const getContacts = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(url, apiHeaders);
    const allContacts = response.data.contacts;
    return allContacts;
}
getContacts()


module.exports = app => {
app.get('/contacts' ,(req, res) => {
    res.send(getContacts())})
};
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score -2):

Boa noite;

Se a requisição vier no formato Json eu imagino que você precisa colocar um `app.use(express.json());`
quando usa o express ele já faz essa declaração para você.